# Alternative syntax for angular.module.controller

Tags: angularjs

I have module with directive and application which is module with controllers.

```
angular.module('ValidationWidgets', [])
    .directive('validationfield', function () {
         ....
    });


angular.module('MyPage', ['ValidationWidgets'])
       .controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope) {

        ....
    });
```

Is there some pretty syntax to declare many controllers in app module, because `.controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope) {` looks bad?

I want to write something like:

```
var myPage = angular.module('MyPage', ['ValidationWidgets']);

myPage.controllers.MyFirstController = function($scope) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("my controller", function(){});
```

or

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
var controllers = {};
controller.myController = function(){};
app.controller(controllers);
```

Take a look at this video http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-thinking-different-about-organization/

The whole series is amazing to be honest.

Comment: I believe you can also just have your router load in the controller from a function declaration. Although this makes it less obvious that the function declaration is indeed a controller.

Comment: I think that should read `controllers.myController`… but I can't make a single character edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @Jacob Dalton said, you can do this:

Setup your routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/view1', controller: 'View1Ctrl'}).
        when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/view1', controller: 'View2Ctrl'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Then you can declare your controllers by simply declaring a function:

```
function View1Ctrl($scope, $http) {
}

function View2Ctrl($scope, $http) {
}
```

Those functions will be auto wired as controllers. As stated before, however, this makes it less obvious that these functions are controllers.

Comment: View1Ctrl should be in global scope, is't it? Or this functions can be inside other object scope?